# Queues race condition and threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, race-condition

I've started to develop some features for a network application and I've ran into some problems.
I have 2 threads that i need to communicate between. One writes to a queue and the other reads from it. I didn't think there could be a race condition in this situation, but i guess i was wrong. I tried implementing this by using queue.empty() to see if there is an item in the queue, and if so to read and pop it. This didn't work and i got into some race condition with the empty function. Is it possible to solve it without using concurrent queues or do i have too?

If there is another solution, rather than concurrent queues, if i have 2 writing threads and 1 reading thread will it still work?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to synchronize threads using a mutex? As long as you have a mutable shared resource, you should do it.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you meant. Did you mean to add mutex lock to every function in queue?

Comment: You must prevent a thread from reading the queue while another thread writes into it and vice versa. For that you can use a mutex to lock reading and writing from/to the queue.

Comment: Re, "I didn't think there could be a race condition in this situation." You have the potential for race conditions _any_ time two threads both use the same shared data (e.g., the same shared queue). The naive solution is to have a mutex along side of the queue, and make sure that every thread always locks the mutex before doing anything with the queue, and always unlocks the mutex afterward (`std::lock_guard` is good for that!) But, there may be other, more sophisticated solutions that give better performance.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, u helped me solve it!